# Options and type determinations f#

Tags: types, f#

I'm doing a project called "2dShapeEditor" where you are supposed to be able to  create, click and drag different kind of shapes on a form. At the stage of the project I am at right now, i need to determine what kind of type my targeted rectangle is. It's initialized as an "Option" but can through a "hittest" change to the specific rectangle that is clicked.

I will then apply my move method to this rectangle making it move with the mouse.

My type RectangleZ

```
type RectangleZ(x:int, y:int)= 
  let mutable thisx = x
  let mutable thisy = y
  let mutable thiswidth = 50
  let mutable thisheight = 20
  let brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black)
  member obj.x with get () = thisx and set x = thisx <- x
  member obj.y with get () = thisy and set y = thisy <- y
  member obj.width with get () = thiswidth and set width = thiswidth <- width
  member obj.height with get () = thisheight and set height = thisheight <- height
  member obj.thisColor = Color.FromArgb(167, 198, 253)
  member obj.draw(paper:Graphics) = paper.FillRectangle(brush, thisx, thisy, 50, 20)
  member obj.ShapeType = "Rectangle"
```

My hittest method:

```
let rec getShape (e:MouseEventArgs) (inputl:List<RectangleZ>) = match inputl with 
                                                               |[] -> None
                                                               |s::tail->if(((e.X >= s.x) && (s.x <= (s.x + s.width))) && ((e.Y >= s.y) && (e.Y <= (s.y + s.height)))) then Some(s) else getShape e tail //Some(s)
```

My targeted rectangle look like this:

```
let mutable targetedRec = None
```

My "Move()" method looks like this:

```
let Move (e:MouseEventArgs) = if(targetedRec = None) then None else targetedRec.Value.x <- e.X
                                                                    targetedRec.Value.y <- e.Y
```

The "Move()" method gives me the error: "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this
program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

And yes, the compiler gives me a hint of what's wrong and how to fix it, i've tried with matching, if statements, I simply don't understand what's wrong and how to fix it. If I remove the Option type of the targetedRec and just put it as a type of "RectangleZ" alot of my project will fail because i can't leave blank if statements. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried giving `targetedRec` a type?

Comment: yes, targetedRec is currently an option

Comment: Does `Value` have a specified type?

Comment: `Value` is a property of the type `Option`

Comment: Maybe i should add my `RectangleZ` type to the question aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type is inferred for 'targetedRec'? (You can tell by hovering the mouse over it and looking at the Intellisense tooltip.)

From what you've posted, the F# compiler is only able to infer the type of 'targetedRec' as `'a option` -- that is, the compiler knows it's an Option (because you've assigned `None` to it), but it can't tell what the type parameter of the option is supposed to be. Then, you see the error in your `Move` method because the compiler can't tell what type the `x` and `y` fields belong to.

This is pretty easy to fix though -- just add a type annotation to your declaration for `targetedRec`, like so:

```
let mutable targetedRec : RectangleZ option = None
```

That alone should fix the problem, but you can clean up your `Move` method a bit too by using pattern matching instead of manually checking the `Value` property:

```
let Move (e : MouseEventArgs) =
    match targetedRec with
    | None -> ()
    | Some targetedRec ->
        targetedRec.x <- e.X
        targetedRec.y <- e.Y
```

Comment: You need to return `Some targetedRec` in the `Some targetedRec` branch in order that the function is type-checked.

Comment: Thanks @pad, nice catch. That's what I get for writing up the code in Notepad ;)

Comment: I bow to your superior expertise. Thank you for your help!